# Ограничение на скачивание в mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mariadb, резервное-копирование, putty, dump

Написал команду

```
mysqldump -u user -p4vZ5iKK6PZ7U8jrh qntsoftapi > qntsoftapi.sql
```

База веси 6.3гб, а задампило 1862701кб - 1,862701гб
Почему произошёл не полный дамп или почему база такая худая в сравнении с той что в phpmyadmin?
P.S. Ошибок дамп никаких не выдал и по его мнению выполнил его работу
P.S.S. Возможно я просто не знаю какой-то особенности и поэтому задал этот глупый вопрос. Расскажите пожалуйста что да как)

Comment: Почему вы решили что неполный? Формат разный, размер совсем не обязан совпадать. Всякие служебные структуры innodb тоже занимают често например, но в дамп попадать не будут за ненадобностью

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, спасибо за ответ, надеюсь что оно так и есть)
Можете написать это в ответ помечу как верный если оно так и есть позже)